# Div will not go 100% height with CSS

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked a lot, and I'm used to making a div fill 100% of the window height using CSS, however, with the specific code I'm using here, I can't seem to get the `.entry-header` element to fill 100% of the visible height of the window, despite it's parent `article` being able to do so with the exact same code.

I have a pen showing the HTML/CSS I have so far: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JBbCu

I wish to get the `.entry-header` element to fill the height of the screen, with the `.entry-overlay` element sitting at the bottom of it, followed by the content of the article below the fold.

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

you have to do:

```
article {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You can analyse it by firebug (firefox)

Comment: I've done this with the * selector which would apply to html/body

Comment: Firebug is pretty old now. Most browsers themselves have tools built-in which allow you to view things like this anyway.

Comment: height doesn't work either. Min height on the article does work.

Comment: Use height 100% on body html and all divs above your div

Comment: Thanks, the issue now seems to be that the article collapses after the header, as the background isn't applied to the content